# $S=\{x_n:x_n$ be a bounded string in $ \mathbb{R} \}$, with $k\in\mathbb{R}$, show that $S$ isn't compact with respect to sup norm.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $S=\{x_n:x_n$ be a bounded string in $\mathbb{R}\}$, with $k\in\mathbb{R}$ and $d((x_n),(y_n))=\sup\{|x_n-y_n|:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Show that $(S,d)$ is not compact.

I did it like this:

> We know if $(S,d)$ is a metric space, then $(S, d)$ is compact if and
> only if $(S, d)$ is complete and totally bounded.
>
> Let $S=\{x_n:|x_n|\le k\}$, with $k\in\mathbb{R}$ and
> $d((x_n),(y_n))=\sup\{|x_n-y_n| :N\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Now let's take a
> closed set $F=\{a_1, a_2, a_3, ...\}$ such that $$a_1=(k,0,0,0,...)$$
> $$a_2=(0,k,0,0,...)$$ $$\vdots$$ $$a_n=(0,0,0,...,k,...)$$
>
> Note that $F$ is not completely bounded, as for $\varepsilon=\frac{k}{2}$
> any ball $B (a, \varepsilon)$ in $S$ cannot contain more than one
> point of $ F$. So for this $\varepsilon$ one cannot obtain a finite
> set $F=\{a_1,...,a_n\}\in S$ such that $F\displaystyle\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^n B (a_i,\varepsilon)$.

But I'm not sure if this is enough.
Is it enough? If not, how can I do it?

Comment: the sequence $\{a_n\}$ that you presented is highly related. But what do you mean by $x_n$ being _"bounded string in $\mathbb{R}$"_?

Comment: Also it's not clear what is $k$ used for, in you definitions before your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Under the metric $d$, the set $F$ is compact if and only if $F$ is sequentially compact. But the sequence $\{a_n\}$ satisfies $d(a_n, a_m) = k$ for $n \ne m$. This means that there is no convergent subsequence, for such a sequence would be Cauchy.